# Resize Retina NSBitmapImage to Half Size

Tags: objective-c, image, macos, cocoa

First I'm creating a `CGImageRef`

```
CGImageRef imageRef = [self createCGimageOfDocumentInPath:scaledSelection withBackgroundColor:self.backgroundColor];
```

Then I am creating an `NSBitmapImageRep`

```
imageData = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithCGImage:imageRef];
```

Then I'm making the image Retina (144pixels/inch)

```
     NSSize newSize;
     newSize.width = [imageData pixelsWide] * 72.0 / 144;  // x-resolution
     newSize.height = [imageData pixelsHigh] * 72.0 / 144;  // y-resolution
     [imageData setSize:newSize];
```

In my debugger, it says that
my `imageData->NSImageRep->_size = NSSize(320/240)`
the `pixelsWide = 640` and `pixelsHigh = 480`

That looks correct, I want the size of the image to be 320/240, but I want it to be retina so I want the pixels to be double that, right?

When I save this image and load it, it ends up having a height/width of 640/480-- but also the 144pixels/inch (retina)

So I think I just need a way to resize my image in half before I save it, or maybe I'm going about this the wrong way?  Has anybody done anything like this before?

Answer (score 1):

So as it turns out, OSX records which images were captured using the screenshot tool, then tells Preview to open that image in half size.  So it isn't actually possible to create an image that opens half size in Preview, unless you mess with the OS files somewhere.  It doesn't really matter though because if you open an image taken with the screenshot tool in Chrome or another app besides Preview, it also opens at double size.  So it seems to just be special casing Apple created for Preview+Built-in Screenshots.

This of course is all personal speculation because I couldn't actually find any documentation or more information on this-- I can tell you, however, that I created an exact replica of a built-in screenshot image.  Including all of the metadata and properties associated with the image, and it still opened differently in Preview.

I tried changing any pertinent property in NSBitmapImageRef, CGImage, CGContext, to try to get this.  Tried changing the NSEXIFProperties as well, to no avail.  (Related, no matter what you change in the metadata it doesn't change the actual image-- turns out they're just labels.  Which makes sense, because I've seen gifs with the .jpeg extension)

Here's an article of somebody who scales the image opened in preview back out, but that's the opposite of what I wanted to do

http://www.macissues.com/2014/03/29/adjust-retina-macbook-screenshots-to-be-actual-size/

Anyways, after much digging, I'm afraid I'm going to have to mark this case closed, for now.  If anybody stumbles across this and finds a solution, please message me :)